# Passing two variables through the .indexOf() in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I've been looking through some js source and found someone using the indexOf() method. However, instead of passing a single parameter, they passed two like this:

```
string.indexOf(a,5)
```

where 'a' was a predefined string. What does this mean? Is it just indexing more than one parameter? Of so, what does it return?

Comment: string.indexOf(searchvalue,start)

Answer (score 1):

From [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```
arr.indexOf(searchElement[, fromIndex = 0])
```

Where `fromIndex` is defined as:

> **The index to start the search at.** If the index is greater than or equal to the array's length, -1 is returned, which means the array will not be searched. If the provided index value is a negative number, it is taken as the offset from the end of the array. Note: if the provided index is negative, the array is still searched from front to back. If the calculated index is less than 0, then the whole array will be searched. Default: 0 (Entire array is searched).

So `string.indexOf(a,5)` will look for `a` in `string` starting at the character with index `5`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Makes so much more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help.

string.indexOf(searchvalue,start);

searchvalue = Required. The string to search for

start = Optional. Default 0. At which position to start the search